# Alfresco dashlet path in a variable

Tags: javascript, alfresco, dashlet

I've created a dashlet which gives the content (sub folder) of a folder, if I write the path in the dashlet code it works fine. But I'd like to let the user choose the folder he wants to list.

So, first I'd try the simplest things that come in my mind: open a dialog when the config button is triggered, then the user write the path and press valid. My question is how can I handdle the path variable, I try to put the path in a variable but I don't think it is a good idea, my thoughts are that the `/` caracters messed up the thing. I've got an error 500 as soon as I try to put the variable value in the `get.js` file.

```
var title = args.title;
var userName = user.name;
var path = args.path;
```

It works fine for the title but as soon as I add the path variable here's come the error 500.

So Is there any special way to handdle this? Or do I use another kind of dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this once, but in cases of paths and queries it's too much work to encode and decode the '/' in the path.

I'd suggest directly try to implement a folder-picker in the dashlet.
It's a bit of more work to get it done, but it's also nicer to have.

1. Custom [dashlet](https://github.com/share-extras/document-list-dashlet) with a folder picker in it
2. Old [tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/05/15/1599) which will need some work to get it probably done on your version of Alfresco

Comment: thanks a lot Tahir, using a folder-picker was my second idea as soon as I understand that the '/' was a problem. I've asked just to be sure that there is no kind of "super variable" that allows that :) and your answer just strengthen me that folder-picker is the best option. Thanks again